# adding dash between spaces in field name in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have database in mysql & have maintain 3 columns i.e. ID , name, slug.

Slug column is same as name but here I put combination of name column. Suppose if name is Micky Mehta then in slug I want it should show micky-mehta. In slug I want everything in small letters & if space then it should be replaced with dash. All this because I want SEO friendly url for my site. Now I can do this with program when new products gets added but is it also possible If I can directly do that with mySQL? I mean is there any function in mySQL which perform this kind of task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update data to fit your scheme:

```
UPDATE mytable SET slug = REPLACE(LOWER(name), ' ', '-');
```

If you want it to happen automatically every time you add a new row or update an existing row, you can use triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SetSlugIns BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
  FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.slug = REPLACE(LOWER(NEW.name), ' ', '-');

CREATE TRIGGER SetSlugUpd BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
  FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.slug = REPLACE(LOWER(NEW.name), ' ', '-');
```

In MySQL 5.7, they now have [generated columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html), so you can do the same thing without writing triggers:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(100),
  slug VARCHAR(100) AS (REPLACE(LOWER(name), ' ', '-')
);
```

Comment: Thanks Bill. This is exactly what I wanted

Comment: By executing this query it shows "You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)" .

Comment: I'm guessing you are using Amazon RDS. This disables creation of triggers by default, but you can change a configuration option to permit it. Read https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-functions/

Comment: Is that a paid service?

Comment: Amazon RDS is a paid service, yes. Changing a configuration option in RDS does not change the cost.

Answer (score 0):

Try This
example-

```
UPDATE yourTable SET yourColumn = LOWER(replace('Your Value', ' ', '_'))
```

Comment: No need to specify id if you want to replace all columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with your programming language. If you are coding in php you can do it as below
Take a new variable say `$slug`

```
$name='Jone Doe'; //the name value you getting from form or input

//convert string into lower. It will give you 'jon doe'
$nameInLower = strtolower($name); 

// now replace space with hyphen.
$slug=str_replace(' ', '-',$nameInLower);
```

Insert the `$slug` variable in your database table along with the `name` column(considering `id` is auto incremented column.

Comment: Refer to Bill Karwin's answer because it's awesome.